# Drawerlayout children views overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I've been trying to make a `DrawerLayout` that has a `ViewPager` and a `LinearLayout` attached to the bottom of the `DrawerLayout`. The problem is that the `ViewPager` and `LinearLayout` are overlapping at the top of the view, and all my efforts to move the `LinearLayout` down have failed so far.

The XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/tabstrip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/base_activity_viewpager"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:textIsSelectable="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Naviagtion drawer -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've tried adding several things to linear_layout:

1. `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` (causes an IllegalStateException)
2. `android:layout_below="@id/viewpager"`
3. `android:layout_alignparentbottom="true"`

But all of these values seem to be ignored, even changing `android:layout_width` of the `LinearLayout` is ignored. I think i'm overlooking something obvious but if anyone has suggestions on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A drawerlayout is allowed only 2 children, the first is a main content view, the second is the drawer. You need to combine your first two views into a linear layout. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Can the second child be somthing other than a listview, for instance a linearlayout or any other view? 

I tried to put a linearlayout with android:layout_gravity="start" and I had this error: 

ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: @BigDan It's possible, but make sure you pass correct object (your LinearLayout) for methods `isDrawerOpen`, `closeDrawer` etc.