# DrawerLayout background for ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have the following for my `DrawerLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to have a background image for my `ListView` with a black view on top of it that has some opacity. For my iPhone app it's very easy--I just have a `UIImageView` with a `UIView` on top that has a black background and opacity of .4 and everything works.

Is there a way to do this in Android? Also, this image will be downloaded from the server...so I need to fit that constraint as well.

**EDIT**

I tried as per the first answer below and got the below error:

```
Process: com.mounzaapp, PID: 17534
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mounzaapp/com.mounzaapp.views.dashboard.DashboardFragmentActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:857)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1058)
        at com.mounzaapp.views.dashboard.DashboardFragmentActivity.onItemClick(DashboardFragmentActivity.java:257)
        at com.mounzaapp.views.dashboard.DashboardFragmentActivity.onCreate(DashboardFragmentActivity.java:148)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

I get the error when doing: `drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listLayout);` . `listLayout` is the `RelativeLayout` that contains the `ListView`.

**EDIT 2**

Turns out all I had to do was delete the app from my android device and then rebuild. Everything else worked!

Comment: Did you tried adding your `ListView` to a `Layout` and setting this `Layout`'s background accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only put two child views inside a `DrawerLayout`, but you can put the `ListView` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- RelativeLayout to display slider menu -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

        <!-- Whatever view you want inside the RelativeLayout -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**** EDIT ****

[Only two child view in DrawerLayout reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694846/1650683)

Comment: I'm having issues closing the drawer with the above code...and my application wont start :(. Put the error on my question.

Comment: Please show the code of how you integrate the `DrawerLayout` in you Activity. According to you error log:  `android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams`, looks like you use the wrong kind of `LayoutParams`

Comment: @westlinkin, how many child elements do you see in original question of OP ? Can you add reference to >`You can only put two child views inside a DrawerLayout`

Comment: Turns out all I had to do was rebuild and then delete the app from the phone. Rest worked!

Comment: @nmxprime Edited the answer to add reference