# DrawerLayout and ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am getting a `DrawerLayout and ActionBarDrawerToggle  cannot be resolved to a type` compile error.I am added an import to my project.But I am getting an error again.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;  --->DrawerLayout undefined
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle; ---->undefined error

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       }
      }
```

Comment: have you added android-support-v4.jar to your libs folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have more than two direct children in your `DrawerWidget`. Right now, you have three direct children in your widget. That is the reason you are getting error in you xml. I have created a sample project for custom Drawer Layout. Please check it [here](https://github.com/droiddev24/DrawerSample). I think you'll get everything you need in that project.

Looking at your layout, it looks like you need to have custom layouts in your Drawer widget. Please keep in mind that `DrawerWidget` only supports two direct children. Think of it as having two xml files combined in one layout.xml file.

First child of `DrawerWidget` is the main content view which will be shown as the normal screen. Think of this as the xml file that you have to show on your main screen. You can have a `RelativeLayout` here and add anything in it which will be shown on main screen.

Second child of `DrawerLayout` is the slider, which will slide-out when you click the button to show slider. Think of this as another xml file, which will only be shown when slider is shown. You can have `RelatvieLayout` here too.

What layouts you are using in it, totally depends on what kind of view you need. But don't forget, **only two direct children** rule with `DrawerLayout`.

Check the sample project for more information. It contains everything custom, so will help you to have a better idea.

**NOTE:** Also please don't forget to add `android-support-v4.jar` to libs folder of you project.

Comment: I removed the two library gson and libgoogleanalytics but still error occurred.

Comment: Its not about those libraries, as in your question, you stated _ I am getting this error.Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup_. It is just because of the reason that you have more than two __direct__ children in your `DrawerWidget`. Let me edit my answer for more clarification.

Comment: I am understood now I have three direct children.ok I try to rectify it.

Comment: Please read it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16694846/2389078) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). I don't know how you managed to get it to work. But, in my understanding, `DrawerLayout` can't have more than two children.

Comment: Thank you your suggestion helped me to solve a problem.

Comment: Its nice to hear, it helped you. Going to add it to answer as well. :D

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have imported the DrawerLayout class properly.Check your import statement.It should be something like this.

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
```

---

### what about Order and Export tab

did all options checked?

Comment: yes.It was like that.But I am getting an compile error.Same thing I am posted in the question too

Comment: what about Order and Export tab? @Naruto

Comment: yes everything checked.I am edited the post and added order and export

Comment: Check this

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

For more info on NaigationDrawer

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html                                                                                                                               check this also    http://stackoverflow.com/a/17046681/1761003

Comment: Right now I am using kitkat version api level 19 .So that error occurred as per this doc `http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html`