# How to display Navigation Drawer below Viewpager tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

My Navigation Drawer works just fine!!

But i want to modify it such as to display drawer below viewpager tabs.

---

I have used Navigation Drawer by adding it into my activity and then accessed it but this time the scenario is different and want to display drawer below tabs.

Can i add Navigation Drawer in fragment layout and access it from fragment class or if its not possible / recommended then how can i achieve the same.

Please refer attached screenshot for problem understanding.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You might need a custom [`DrawerLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26730570/2389078) here

Answer (score 1):

You have two way to achieve this.

**1. Method One, the sustainable**

Use support.v7.Toolbar in your Layout and placing correctly your NavigationDrawer will feet your need. Moreover, it's more durable.

**2. Method two: the old one**

Use ActionBar Tabs see http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs 
The main part is

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    ...

    // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // hide the given tab
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // probably ignore this event
        }
    };

    // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
```